# Can't run C++ .exe created by VSCode

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-code, exe

I use VSCode to create the .exe file of the simple following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 25;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I open the .exe program created, the window appears and shuts down immediately. If I put getchar() before return 0, I can make the program wait for user input to fix it. However, if I use Dev-C or Codeblocks, this problem does not happen. In other word, I do not need to add getchar() to hold the window. Hope that someone can explain what problem occurs and how can I fix it to make the .exe created by VSCode run normally? Thank you so much.

Comment: use the integrated terminal, not an external terminal, the feature of Dev-C is that Dev-C holds the terminal for you, it is not something to be fixed, the program runs in the terminal and the terminal closes when the program terminates, you can start the program yourself in a terminal you start yourself

Comment: If I want to send the .exe file to someone, how can they run it? Since they will use the terminal available in their computer, which can be not integrated terminal in VSCode?

Comment: then they don't have this close problem because they start a terminal and execute the program with a shell command